# installing libraries for cygwin

Tags: linux, installation, cygwin, libraries

I want to install these libraries in cygwin, how do I do it? are all of them available on cygwin environment or only on linux?

- g++ - the version 4.4
- graphviz
- gnuplot
- plotdrop
- libboost version 1.38
- libgsl0-dbg
- libgsl0-dev
- libgsl0ldbl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the official [Cygwin Package List](http://www.cygwin.com/packages/).  This includes all the packages you can install via the Cygwin installer ([link](http://www.cygwin.com/setup.exe)), and allows searching and examining the package contents before you install it.

Note that Cygwin doesn't necessarily use the same package names (like *libgsl0-dev*, etc) that other Linux distributions use.

- **g++ v4.4**: Cygwin's latest GCC is gcc4-4.3.4-3 (note the separate *gcc4* package name; the normal *gcc* package is version 3.4.4).  If you need newer you'll have to install from source.
- **graphviz**: not available as a Cygwin package(?); install the [Windows version](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php)
- **gnuplot**: latest package is [gnuplot-4.2.4-1](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=gnuplot%2Fgnuplot-4.2.4-1&grep=plot)
- **plotdrop**: not available as a Cygwin package(?); install from source
- **libboost**: latest package is [boost-1.33.1-4](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=boost%2Fboost-1.33.1-4&grep=graphviz) (and the corresponding *boost-devel* package); for the more recent version, install from source
- **gsl**: latest packages are [gsl-1.13-2](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=gsl%2Fgsl-1.13-2&grep=gsl) (runtime DLLs), [gsl-devel-1.13-2](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=gsl-devel%2Fgsl-devel-1.13-2&grep=gsl) (header files, libgsl.a, etc), [gsl-apps-1.13-2](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=gsl-apps%2Fgsl-apps-1.13-2&grep=gsl) (GSL utilities), and [gsl-1.13-2-src](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=gsl%2Fgsl-1.13-2-src&grep=gsl) (source) are available.  there isn't a *dbg* package (which usually contains debugging symbols for the libraries or programs in a package); for that you'll probably want to grab the source code and compile your own version.